# How to call a foreach select box in controller to a blade view with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, foreach, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 and I have a field which is a selectbox, and I call it in the controller to show in my view. But The value of the selectbox does not appear. When my code in the controller like this:

```
foreach($getDataListPengikut as $dtListPengikut):
        $msg["opt"] .= '<tr>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="name_{{ $dtListPengikut->KODE }}" name="name[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
                <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>
                    @foreach ($getPengikut as $getPeng)
                        <option value="{{ $getPeng->KODE }}">{{ $getPeng->DESKRIPSI }}</option> 
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </td> 
            <td><input type="text" value="'.$dtListPengikut->KETERANGAN.'" id="ket_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="ket[]" placeholder="Keterangan" class="form-control ket_list" style="text-transform:uppercase" required="false" />
            </td>    
            <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add2" class="btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
            </td>
        </tr>';
    $no++;
    endforeach;
```

In the inside of my selectbox is  `{{ $getPeng->DESKRIPSI }}`

And when I change my code into like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="name[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
<option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>
'. foreach($getPengikut as $getPeng) .'
    <option value="'. $getPeng->KODE.'"> '.$getPeng->DESKRIPSI.' </option> 
'.endforeach.'
</select>
```

I got an error :

> syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In the view file :

<select class="form-control" id="name_{{ $dtListPengikut->KODE }}" name="name[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
 <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>
  @foreach ($getPengikut as $getPeng)
        <option value="{{ $getPeng->KODE }}">{{ $getPeng->DESKRIPSI }}</option> 
  @endforeach
</select>


In in the controller:
$html = '<select class="form-control" id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="name[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
    <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>';
    foreach($getPengikut as $getPeng):
        $html .= '<option value="'. $getPeng->KODE.'"> '.$getPeng->DESKRIPSI.'</option>' ;
    endforeach;
$html .='</select>';
```

Comment: You might want to add some description to your code.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the wrong syntax. Use `{{ expression }}` instead of `"'.`. The correct syntax is:

```
<select class="form-control" id="name_{{ $dtListPengikut->KODE }}" name="name[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
<option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>
    @foreach ($getPengikut as $getPeng)
        <option value="{{ $getPeng->KODE }}">{{ $getPeng->DESKRIPSI }}</option> 
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: if i put that on my view blade it is correct. but my problem is I put it on my controller. And if I put it in my controller it is still the same `{{ $getPeng->DESKRIPSI }}` inside my dropdown. I already update the controller code in my question

Comment: @hendraspt even if you put it in a controller, you're using the wrong syntax for `foreach`. Also, as I'm showing in my repo, [putting HTML into a controller](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#do-not-put-js-and-css-in-blade-templates-and-do-not-put-any-html-in-php-classes) is a terrible idea. Move all HTML into Blade templates as I've shown and everything will work.